# How can I execute a kdb verb function on a remote server without using the string format?

Tags: kdb

I want to assign a variable on a remote server using the 'set' and 'sv' verbs. How can I execute verbs and store the results remotely without using the string notation?

```
q)h (set; a; 3)
'a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a as a symbol, like the following:

```
h(set;`a;3)
```

Comment: How can I assign a remote variable using sv? I tried h (sv; `a; "/", "/mydir", "path") but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't believe you can assign a variable like that. I assume you're following Ryan's 3rd suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616579/how-can-i-evaluate-a-q-script-in-a-running-kdb-server) . Here he is suggesting to use sv to build the path, rather than assign the variable. Have a look at the wiki for sv [here](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/sv) .

Comment: Thanks. I can build the path locally and then use set to assign variables remotely. Still, I wonder what breaks the sv remote invocation...

Comment: if you have the value and the name locally, send them over like this: `h(set;\`a;1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
q)h:hopen 5002
q)h (sv;`;`:a/b,`c)
`:a/b/c
```

Comment: What does the backtick semicolon do in this call? And can I assign the result to a remote variable?

Comment: `(sv;\`;\`:a/b,\`c)` is a parse tree which is evaluated on the server. See here http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/parse_tree . It's not backtick-semicolon but rather a list of 3 elements, `sv`, `\`` and `\`:a/b,\`c`